# Spy on function returned from 3rd party library hook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am not able to figure out hot to spy on `navigate` function returned by `useNavigation` hook from **React navigation** v5.

I have a simple `Link` component:

```
const Link = props => {
  const { to, children, ...restProps } = props;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handlePress = useCallback(() => navigation.navigate(to), [navigation, to]);

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity testID="link" onPress={handlePress}>
      <Text
        {...restProps}
      >
        {children}
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};
```

and coresponding test:

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native'),
  useNavigation: () => ({
    navigate: jest.fn(() => 'mocked navigate'),
  }),
}));

import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const spy = jest.spyOn(useNavigation, 'navigate');

describe('<Link />', () => {
  it('navigates', () => {
    const link = render(<Link to="TestScreen">Test link</Link>);
    fireEvent.press(link.getByTestId('link'));

    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```

Of course this won't work, because in `const spy = jest.spyOn(useNavigation, 'navigate');` `navigate` isn't function of `useNavigation`. But I tried countless other possibilities and I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Basically what I am trying to do is to verify that when the link is pressed, it calls expected function with expected parameter and I want the function to be mocked out.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late, but I had the same issue and wanted to know when did the navigate function was called.

For it, I mocked the function this way, so the `mockedNavigate` would be a jest function that I could use later:

```
const mockedNavigate = jest.fn();

jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native'),
    useNavigation: () => ({
      navigate: mockedNavigate,
    }),
  };
});
```

This allowed me to use this later, and in this case you will not need to spy anymore, this should do the trick:

```
expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello for those looking for vitest you could use it like:

```
const mockedNavigate = vi.fn();
vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
    const reactRouterDom = await vi.importActual('react-router-dom') as object;
    return {
        ...reactRouterDom,
        useNavigation: () => (mockedNavigate),
    };
});
```

Then the expect will be like:

```
expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Comment: Hey please note that I made a typo it is not "useNavigation", it is "useNavigate"